# Creating efficient PDO functions

Tags: php5, pdo

I have the following functions:

```
 function getExample($id, $otherid) {
            global $db;
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM examples WHERE id = :id AND otherid= :otherid';
            try { 
                $statement = $db->prepare($query);
                $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
                $statement->bindValue(':otherid', $otherid);
                $statement->execute();
                $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                $statement->closeCursor();
                return $result;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $error_message = $e->getMessage();
                display_db_error($error_message);
            }
        }

 function getSecExample($id) {
            global $db;
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM examples WHERE id= :id';
            try { 
                $statement = $db->prepare($query);
                $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
                $statement->execute();
                $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                $statement->closeCursor();
                return $result;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $error_message = $e->getMessage();
                display_db_error($error_message);
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to make this one function instead of two? I want it to be secure and done with the best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think that forcing this into one function will make it a "best practice," and that doesn't seem right anyways.

I suppose one way you could do it is:

```
 WHERE id = :id AND otherid LIKE :otherid
```

If it were to be in the second function, `:otherid` would be a wildcard (`%`). Otherwise just have your value. [Check out this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement).

Comment: The reason I was asking, is because I have a lot of functions like that; they are quite a bit the same. I was hoping to somehow combine some of them together so I had less functions to deal with. I appreciate your response.